# Use only preg_replace() or combine preg_match() and preg_replace()?

Tags: php, regex, performance, preg-replace, preg-match

I'm need to replace string with some pattern in array if needed pattern exists:

```
$patterns = [
   'PATTERN#1' => 'REPLACE#1',
   'PATTERN#2' => 'REPLACE#2',
];

$string = 'SOME STRING TO PREG_REPLACE';
```

Which way will be faster:

```
// PREG_REPLACE ONLY FOR MATCHED PATTERN:
foreach ($patterns as $pattern => $replace) {
    if (preg_match($string, $pattern)) {
        preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $string);
        break;
    }
}
```

or

```
// PREG_REPLACE FOR ALL PATTERNS:
foreach ($patterns as $pattern => $replace) {
    preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $string);
    break;
}
```

Comment: Only `replace` will be faster - it doesn't need to match twice. Have you tested it? Is the simpler solution too slow?

Comment: Why do you `break;` the loop after the first pattern?

Answer (score 4):

`preg_replace` takes array arguments for pattern and replacement.

```
preg_replace(array_keys($patters), array_values($patterns), $string);
```